# Turn off animations in Capybara tests

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, animation, capybara

I have a lot of animations on my page, which really slows down my tests in capybara because capybara often have to wait until a element has been animated, as it starts out hidden.

I found this solution for all jQuery based animations:

`<%= javascript_tag '$.fx.off = true;' if Rails.env.test? %>`

However i use twitter bootstrap and most animations from bootstrap is made by CSS 3 (with javascript fallback). So my question is, is there a way to turn of CSS 3 transitions and animations in tests?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try to create some transition reset and apply it on a specific element.

```
.reset-transition {
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition: none;
    -ms-transition: none;
    -o-transition: none;
    transition: none;
}
```

You can also apply it to ALL and place this css after Bootstrap

```
* {
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition: none;
    -ms-transition: none;
    -o-transition: none;
    transition: none;
}
```

You can make it more specific

```
div, a, span, footer, header {
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition: none;
    -ms-transition: none;
    -o-transition: none;
    transition: none;
}
```

Answer (score 38):

Starting from Capybara [v3.2.0](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/3.2.0/Capybara%2FSessionConfig:disable_animation=):

```
Capybara.disable_animation = true
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Totally fixed problem I was having with Bootstrap 4 modals!

Comment: Thanks man! Exactly what we needed. Works like a charm - no extra production code and flakiness is gone <3

Answer (score 6):

```
# env.rb or spec_helper.rb

Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  opts = {
    extensions: ["#{Rails.root}/features/support/phantomjs/disable_animations.js"] # or wherever
  }

  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, opts)
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
```

```

```
// disable_animations.js
var disableAnimationStyles = '-webkit-transition: none !important;' +
                             '-moz-transition: none !important;' +
                             '-ms-transition: none !important;' +
                             '-o-transition: none !important;' +
                             'transition: none !important;'

window.onload = function() {
  var animationStyles = document.createElement('style');
  animationStyles.type = 'text/css';
  animationStyles.innerHTML = '* {' + disableAnimationStyles + '}';
  document.head.appendChild(animationStyles);
};
```

or only time

```
var disableAnimationStyles = '-webkit-transition-duration: .0s !important;' +
  '-o-transition-duration: .0s !important;' +
'transition-duration: .0s !important;';
```

Comment: is this possible using `headless_chrome` as driver?